# My SQL Update Statement updates even if the value is the same

Tags: sql, sql-update, insert-update

I want to update a column value. But my Update procedure statement updates even the value of the this column is the same.

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET   ColumName=@ParameterName   
WHERE Id=@ParameterId
```

Any Idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you're telling it to update every row where the condition `Id=@ParameterId` is true. Is that not what you're expecting?

Comment: I just want to update a column and it works but if I click to edit button and type the same value, it will make red the color of the this row. That means it has been updated.But normally it shouldn't make red because the value is the same.

Comment: Sounds like a tool problem, not anything SQL related. Which tool are you using when you see this?

Comment: Visual Studio and it gives this mistake by gridview.

Comment: I think it may be indicating updated data this way since even if you update to the same value, a trigger that is set on the row may fire and do other updates. If it didn't show anything, you may be tricked to think that nothing is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional condition `AND (COALESCE(ColumName,'')<>COALESCE(@ParameterName,'')`
 so you're only updating when those are different.

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET   ColumName=@ParameterName   
WHERE (Id=@ParameterId) AND (COALESCE(ColumName,'')<>COALESCE(@ParameterName,''))
```

The `coalsece` in my example assumes that `ColumnName` is of type `varchar` if is a numeric value use `AND (COALESCE(ColumName,0)<>COALESCE(@ParameterName,0)` instead.

Comment: Does this work if @ParameterName or the existing value in ColumName is NULL?

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it gives a syntax error when I write this code.

Comment: Yes I've missed the ending bracket after the second Coalesce :). Edited my answer...

Comment: Still it makes the same mistake. :(

Comment: The above is a valid sql statement unless, as @Joachim Isaksson suggested this could be a tool problem? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error. Well, on my gridview when I update a row, the  color gets red.But the problem is when I just type the same value,even in the this situation the row gets red.

Comment: It gives error if the value is NULL @Joachim Isaksson

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from your post, you are wondering why MySQL is updating even when the value is not changed. Well, you don't check beforehand if the value is really different, so that's just what an update statement with an ID does...